# JDO3.0 enhance failure in GAE 1.7.2

Tags: java, google-app-engine, datanucleus

I use ant to build my GAE WebApp. This is the datanucleus target:

```
<target name="datanucleusenhance" depends="compile"
    description="Performs enhancement on compiled data classes.">
    <enhance_war war="war">
    </enhance_war>
</target>
```

This is the error I got:

org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL
"file:/home/xxxx/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.0_1473617060/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.2/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.2/lib/opt/tools/datanucleus/v1/datanucleus-core-1.1.5.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/war/WEB-INF/lib/datanucleus-core-3.1.0-m5.jar."

I've tried this ant target:

```
<target name="datanucleusenhance" depends="compile" description="Performs enhancement on compiled data classes.">
    <enhance_war war="war">
        <args>
            <arg value="-enhancerVersion" />
            <arg value="v3.1.0" />
        </args>
    </enhance_war>
</target>
```

I've tried to delete "datanucleus-core-1.1.5.jar". The error then is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected exception
    at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhancer.execute(Enhancer.java:76)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhance.<init>(Enhance.java:71)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhance.main(Enhance.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.Enhancer.execute(Enhancer.java:74)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/datanucleus/OMFContext
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.<init>(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:172)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.<init>(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:150)
    at org.datanucleus.enhancer.DataNucleusEnhancer.main(DataNucleusEnhancer.java:1157)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.datanucleus.OMFContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.enhancer.EnhancerLoader.loadClass(EnhancerLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 10 more
```

How can I use JDO3.0 with GAE1.7.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be confusing which versions of dependent jars to use. GAE 1.7.2 uses GAE JDO/JPA plugin v2.x, which in turn needs DataNucleus 3.x. You evidently have (various) DataNucleus 1.x jars present.

Comment: Got the answer. The correct ant target should be:


 <target name="datanucleusenhance" depends="compile"
  description="Performs enhancement on compiled data classes.">
  <enhance_war war="war">
   <args>
    <arg value="-enhancerVersion" />
    <arg value="v2" />
   </args>
  </enhance_war>
 </target>


the version is the DN version. :)

Comment: No, the version is the GAE JDO/JPA plugin version. DataNucleus is a completely separate project and software (that is used by Googles plugin)

Answer (score 5):

Using the GAE plugin for Intellij, I had to remove the default configured orm directory, and specifically add the higher version libraries.

The GAE SDK is organized as such:

```
/lib/user/orm (default persistence libraries I removed)
```

AND

```
/lib/opt/user/datanucleus/v2
```

To access this configuration in IntelliJ, from the context menu for my project:

```
{context menu} -> Open Module Settings -> Libraries -> AppEngine ORM
```

- Use the `[-]` button to remove the jars within this directory:  `/lib/user/orm`
- Use the `[+]` button to add the jars within this directory: `/lib/opt/user/datanucleus/v2`

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer. The correct ant target should be:

```
<target name="datanucleusenhance" depends="compile" description="Performs enhancement on compiled data classes.">
    <enhance_war war="war">
        <args>
            <arg value="-enhancerVersion" />
            <arg value="v2" />
        </args>
    </enhance_war>
</target>
```

the version is the GAE JDO/JPA plugin version.(Thanks DataNucleus!:)